# Golang - How to make single struct works together with multiple structs?

Tags: go

I want to make single struct works together with multiple structs.

In below codes, first query (`rows`) should be single struct because it return single row, while the second query (`anotherquery`) should be multiple struct because it return 5 rows.

Currently, what can I do is I make `rows` & `anotherquery` as multiple struct.

**Below is `server.go`:**

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Gallery struct {
    Title, Content string
}
type Idcontainer struct {
    Stitle, Suri string
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.Get("/post/:uritext", func(c *echo.Context) error {

        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT title, content FROM gallery WHERE uri=$1", c.Param("uritext"))
        anotherquery, err := db.Query("SELECT title AS stitle, uri AS suri FROM archive WHERE uri!=$1 LIMIT 5", c.Param("uritext"))

        gallery := []Gallery{}
        idcontainer := []Idcontainer{}

        for rows.Next() {
            g := Gallery{}
            err := rows.Scan(&g.Title, &g.Content)

            gallery = append(gallery, g)
        }

        for anotherquery.Next() {
            g := Idcontainer{}
            err := anotherquery.Scan(&g.Stitle, &g.Suri)

            idcontainer = append(idcontainer, g)
        }

        type Model struct {
            Galleries    []Gallery
            Idcontainers []Idcontainer
        }
        return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "onlytestingtpl", Model{
            Galleries:    gallery,
            Idcontainers: idcontainer,
        })
    })

    e.Run(":4444")
}
```

Template:

```
{{define "onlytestingtpl"}}
    {{.Title}}<br>
    {{.Content}}

    <h1>ID number:</h1>
    {{range .Idcontainers}}
    <a href='{{.Suri}}'>{{.Stitle}}</a>
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

Comment: Why someone giving negative vote? Comment here if something wrong

Comment: W.Mar, often uncommitted downvotes are for the reason given on the down vote button "hover text": "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". At a guess, I'd say a likely reason is that your question lacks clarity and makes no effort to have a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). [ask].

Comment: It is wrong. This question have research effort and clear about the problem I trying to solve. However, do I need to create new better question? This question has been stained with downvotes

Comment: "stained with downvotes" I'm not sure you understand how [so] works.

Comment: "do I need to create new better question". In my opinion, you should [edit] this question to have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (i.e. without the needless template wrapping, with just static data rather than a database query, etc) and then ask a clear question with respect to that minimal example. To me, this question is completely unclear; you have two slices, I suppose one happens to have only one element, what is it you want the template to output??

Comment: Did you read [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your edit leaves your example not minimal, not complete, *and* not verifiable. I would expect something like https://play.golang.org/p/X3-eME61pH. That example is minimal (no extraneous/irrelevant db queries/files etc), it's complete (all the relevant data, templates, etc are included); and it's verifiable (it runs in isolation on the playground and presumably repeats whatever issue is being asked about) [That code of course would still need a problem statement and a specific question such as "this code gives … but I want …"].

Comment: Yes, I've read MCVE. I cannot remove DB query because this is not single query. I have 2 different query and should know which one come from which query. If remove DB query, I need to explain the query too.

Comment: One question about the MCVE: If the code has been truncated here and there, how it can be verifiable?

Comment: @DaveC: You are pushing it here. Yes, this is not the best formulated question ever, but instead of slapping him with rules and guidelines you can actually help him creating a better question. I see on your profile you are complaining about a serial downvoter. If your other responses are like this I think it is no wonder you attract that kind of aggression.

Comment: @W.Mar: The question is unclear because you post a snippet of code (good) that is way to specific (bad) for the purpose of showing what problem you have. I think what you want is a struct that has another struct one, and a slice of yet another struct. But by reading your question that is not clear (bad) thus the downvotes. So: try to formulate exactly what you want, and make the code as minimal as possible so we don't have to read through sql queries and templates if they are not related to the problem.

Comment: @RickyA "slapping him with rules"... WTF? I politely pointed out a possible reason for the downvotes, I then attempted to help them create a mvce that was answerable, even going so far as to provide an related example of mvce means. The OP's response wrt the database query indicates they clearly don't get it; at that point I gave up. If you want to waste your time on this question go ahead but don't berate me for attempting to help then cutting my loses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the minimal change to your code to make this work would be the following.

Change this:

```
    type Model struct {
        Galleries    []Gallery
        Idcontainers []Idcontainer
    }
    return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "onlytestingtpl", Model{
        Galleries:    gallery,
        Idcontainers: idcontainer,
    })
```

To this:

```
    type Model struct {
        Gallery    Gallery // you said that theres only a single gallery right?
        Idcontainers []Idcontainer
    }
    return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "onlytestingtpl", Model{
        Gallery:    gallery[0],
        Idcontainers: idcontainer,
    })
```

And then change your template to this:

```
{{define "onlytestingtpl"}}
    {{.Gallery.Title}}<br>
    {{.Gallery.Content}}

    <h1>ID number:</h1>
    {{range .Idcontainers}}
    <a href='{{.Suri}}'>{{.Stitle}}</a>
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

I've tried to mock up a simple example here: http://play.golang.org/p/uedcjXalEH

Though you haven't asked for feedback on the code overall, I'll risk adding a few additional comments:

- Consider using * (pointers) to objects rather than making copies each time.
- Consider changing your initial `rows` to work something like this:

  ```
  gallery := Gallery{}
  if !rows.Next() {
      return rows.Err()
  }
  err := rows.Scan(&gallery.Title, &gallery.Content)

  // anotherquery remains the same ...

  return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "onlytestingtpl", Model{
      Gallery:    gallery,
      Idcontainers: idcontainer,
  })
  ```
- This is probably just example code but in production you'll need more error handling of course :)

Hope this helps.